# Not able to connect to internet in RHEL 5

Tags: networking, redhat-enterprise-linux

I just installed red hat enterprise 5 in my laptop and on desktop both. In desktop it is working fine but in laptop it is not showing the eth device. (I tried ifconfig only lo is there). I tried ifup eth0 still nothing happened. The network service in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and in /etc/sysconfig/network are enable. I had ubuntu in my laptop before and I faced same problem with that too. Is there any problem with my laptop? I have my system on dual boot and in win7 networking is running fine. I am not able to connect to the internet only, other devices are working fine.

System conf: Sony vaio E series. 3 GB RAM, intel core i3 2.13 GHZ.

Comment: which chipset does the LAN use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the type of network card you have using the following command.

```
sudo /sbin/lspci
```

Google the network card to find the correct kernel module required.